# Finding the mean on multiple fields

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to figure out a way to code in python on something specific. I am working with a csv data set that runs with the columns; age, sex, bmi, charges, smoker, number of children. My question being, is there a way to find the mean of BMI where the sex is equal to male or female?

I understand that using pandas the following will give me the mean of all columns:

```py
mean_age = df["age"].mean()
```

I have tried (which I did not think would work):

```py
mean_age = df["age"].mean(on "sex" = "male")
```

as well as

```py
mean_age = df["age"].mean("sex" = "male")
```

and

```py
mean_age = df["age"].mean(where( "sex") = "male")
```

I was wondering if I could code something along the lines of the mean on other columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to group that gives me mean and counts on multiple fields:

```
df.groupby(["sex"]).agg(["mean", "count"])
```